# how to write code (when pressing enter enter it will show the next) java

Tags: java

Code I wrote is below  -

```
public class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args){  

    System.out.print(“Hearing in the distance”);

    System.out.print(“Two mandolins like creatures in the “);  

    System.out.print(“dark”);  

    System.out.print(“Creating the agony of ecstacy.”);  

    System.out.println(“                    - George Barker”);  
    }  
}
```

I want to show each print one by one after each enter button pressed.

```
 `
```

Comment: Your question description is not clear. Do you want when you press the enter button then it will print next System.out.print ?

Answer (score 4):

use  [java.util.Scanner](https://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class) 
if you call Scanner.nextLine() your app waits until you write something and press enter or you can press enter without writing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this below - after every enter button press it will print next value of course you can edit the code accordingly

```
private static void printNext(){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count  = 3;
    while(count> 0) {
        if(count == 1){
           System.out.println("Hearing in the distance");
       }else if(count ==2 ){
           System.out.println("Two mandolins like creatures in the");
       }else {
           System.out.println("Creating the agony of ecstacy.");
       }
        count--;
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.